# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException - Jackson Library

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, mixins

I get the below error when I try to deserialize Automobile class. Jackson is trying to search for the field in child element in parent class. How can I make sure jackson uses the appropriate child type for deserialization? I believe I need to use miixins / customer converters. But i'm not sure how to use them in this specific scenario.

Note: In my case all classes except TestMain are in a jar file and I cannot modify the source files.

**Error**

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
>   Unrecognized field "color" (class com.salesportal.proxy.Car), not
>   marked as ignorable (one known property: "name"])

**Automobile.java**

```
public class Automobile {

    private Car[] cars;

    public Car[] getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

    public void setCars(Car[] cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
    }



}
```

**Car.java**

```
public class Car {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

**Corolla.java**

```
public class Corolla extends Car {

    private String color;

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }



}
```

**TestMain.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class TestJSON {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Automobile automobile = new Automobile();
        Corolla corolla = new Corolla();
        corolla.setName("Toyota");
        corolla.setColor("Silver Grey");
        automobile.setCars(new Corolla[]{corolla});

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(automobile));

        Automobile auto = mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(automobile), Automobile.class);
    }

}
```

**JSON String**

```
{"cars":[{"name":"Toyota","color":"Silver Grey"}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Vicky , you can use sub type annotations in JACKSON. The below works for me , with just this change

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.As;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.Id;

@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Corolla.class, name = "color") })
public class Car {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Ramachandran. I can't modify these classes and probably have to use mixins and annotation you suggested. I was also looking for a generic solution which can be applied to all such types in my program without having to specially all parent and child types in my annotation.

Comment: You should use only Jackson or open to other libs ?

Comment: I can only use Jackson . But please do suggest if there is an alternate approach to fallback on if I'm unable to do it with Jackson

Answer (score 1):

`Automobile` class doesn't have color property.

Change this :

```
Automobile auto = mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(automobile), Automobile.class);
```

to this :

```
Corolla auto = mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(automobile.getCars()), Corolla .class);
```

Comment: Thanks @ FreezY. Sorry I should have mentioned. This is just a sample program that I wrote to demonstrate the problem. In the actual scenario , I have  a huge JSON with a number of arrays. I was kind of looking for a generic solution which I could apply to all arrays are having child types. All I want to deserialize Automobile.  I believe the error is because Car does nit have color property.